# Monthly salary from yearly salary

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to find the month with biggest gap in salary from a table like this:

```
  salary_table
      ID          Salary    fromdate     todate
       1            40000   1994-06-26   1995-06-26
       1            41000   1995-06-26   1996-06-25
       1            42000   1996-06-25   1996-06-25
       2            39000   1998-08-03   1999-08-03
       .
       .
```

The result should be the month in which the difference in the highest and lowest monthly salary were greatest.

I'm sure my current attempt is wrong:

```
SELECT MAX(`salary`) - MIN(`salary`) AS diff, 
YEAR(`from_date`), MONTH(`from_date`) FROM `salaries` 
GROUP BY  YEAR(`from_date`), MONTH(`from_date`)
ORDER BY diff DESC
```

but I´m stuck since I'm only given the interval. Anyone with some suggestion how to tackle this?

Comment: update your question and add the expetced  result

Comment: i updated the post  with regards to the result I want

Comment: is not clear to  me   . show the tabular result you expect

Comment: all employees have a montly salary, but all employees are with the company for a different time span.... thus i want to find out the month in which the difference between the highes and lowest salary was the biggest

Comment: "a month" does not have a gap.  A gap with what?  The question is unclear.

Comment: every month the employees get paid a salary, some higher than the other. I want to find the month in which the gap between the highest and lowest salary is the biggest

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an auxiliary table `salary_month` that will have only two columns: `salary` and `s_month`. For each record in the original `salary` table insert 12 records in `salary_month`, one for each month in range `[fromdate, todate)`. Example procedure for insert:

```
DELIMITER $$

create procedure get_month_salaries()
    MODIFIES SQL DATA   
begin 
    declare _df datetime;   
    declare _salary integer;
    declare _counter integer;
    declare done boolean default false;  
    declare cur cursor for select salary, fromdate from salaries;
    declare continue HANDLER for not found set done := true;

    open cur;

    test_loop: loop
        fetch cur into _salary, _df;
        if done then
          LEAVE test_loop;
        end if;

        set _counter = 0;
        while _counter < 12 do
           insert into salary_month values (_salary, DATE_ADD(_df, INTERVAL _counter MONTH));
           set _counter = _counter + 1;                 
        end while;
      end loop test_loop;
  close cur;          
end$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Then run your current query

```
SELECT MAX(`salary`) - MIN(`salary`) AS diff, 
YEAR(`s_month`), MONTH(`s_month`) FROM `salary_month` 
GROUP BY YEAR(`s_month`), MONTH(`s_month`)
ORDER BY diff DESC
```

on `salary_month` table and you will get the expected result.

Comment: I  had the same idea, but how would i go about creating such a table?

Comment: @FabianHafner Please see the edited answer. Added procedure for inserting records in auxiliary table.

Comment: Thank you for the elaboare answer!